# Iteration and scanning not working as intended

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that solves the "Sokoban" game, so what I'm trying to do currently is to read off a text-file, create a 2D-array, put every single character in that 2d-array (including blankspaces). This is what I'm working on right now, my text file is currently looking like:

```
########
#   # .#
#   $$.#
####   #
   #@ ##
   ####
```

And my code is currently looking as following:

```
package soko;

import java.util.*;


import java.io.*;

public class Dowork {
    File file;
    Scanner sc;
    char a;
    static int lines;
    Scanner lineScanner;
    static int maxChar;
    ArrayList array;
    char[][] array2;
    Scanner bc;
    int n;
    int m;


    public Dowork() throws Exception{
        int n=0;
        int m=0;
        file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/sokoban/readin.txt");
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.reset();
        sc.useDelimiter("s*");
        ArrayList<Character> array = new ArrayList<Character>();
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.next();
            maxChar = line.length();
            if(maxChar < line.length()) {
                maxChar = line.length();
            }
            for (char ch:line.toCharArray()) {
                array.add(ch);
            }
            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        array2 = new char[lines][maxChar];
        Iterator<Character> itemIterator = array.iterator();
            while(itemIterator.hasNext()) {
                itemIterator.next();
                for (int q = 0; q < lines; q++) {
                    for(int r = 0; r < maxChar; r++) {
                        Character j = itemIterator.next();
                        array2[q][r] = itemIterator.next();

                    }
                }

            }
            for (int q = 0; q < lines; q++) {
                for(int r = 0; r < maxChar; r++) {
                    System.out.println(array2[q][r]);
                }
            }


        }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Dowork g = new Dowork();
    }
}
```

My first input on the other hand is:

```
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

.
.
.
```

Obviously there should be 9 # but I only get 7, I'm suspecting something to be wrong with my itemIterator but I cant tell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are overdoing some things. Let's suppose that you know how to read the file. In my try to simplify some things I skipped the actual reading the `.txt`. Instead of that I declared the `String` like your example. Then, I *read* the string line by line and stored that string in the 2D `List`. I hope the code is self-explanatory and easy to transform the result to 2D array (if it's the must).

```
public class Answer1 {

    static final String input =
            "########\n" +
            "#   # .#\n" +
            "#   $$.#\n" +
            "####   #\n" +
            "   #@ ##\n" +
            "   ####";


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<List<String>> grid = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String line: input.split("\n")){
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            row.add(line);
            grid.add(row);
        }

        //test
        System.out.println(grid);

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good idea, thank you for the start, I'll try putting something together around this, I think the whole idea was that it should be looking like you have it now, I just wanted to solve it in the first instance "the wrong way" and then try to optimizine, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just after `String line = sc.next();` you have `maxChar = line.length();`, which means that the condition `if(maxChar < line.length())` immediately after is never satisfied. At the end of the `while(sc.hasNext())` block the variable `maxChar` will simply contain the length of the very last line, which indeed seems to be 7.

By the way, I think you want the condition to be `if(maxChar > line.length())`, if your intention is (as I suspect) for `maxChar` to contain the maximum length of a line in your puzzle file.

Comment: It seems like I have major issues with this code, I thought I was closer when I posted it, but its not counting right on either lines nor maxChar as you mentioned. Guess I was only lucky that I got a decent print anyway, it seems like my biggest problem is the first line of code, where I count maxChar and lines.